# C# Object variable not being returned correctly

Tags: c#, list, oop, object

I have a simple list of `Machine` objects called `loadedMachines`. I add 2 new `Machine` objects to it, with the second argument being the `machineName` attribute.

```
loadedMachines.Add(new Machine("0", "My cool Yaris", "Toyota"));
loadedMachines.Add(new Machine("1", "My sporty car", "Ferrari"));

foreach (Machine m in loadedMachines)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Machine being added is: " + m.machineName);
   }
```

For some reasons my foreach loop is outputting "Machine being added is: " and `m.machineName` seems to not be linking up with my machine objects.

What are the reasons for this? Here is my class definition:

```
public class Machine
{
    public Machine() { }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string machineName { set; get; }
    public string machineType { set; get; }
    public string category { set; get; }
    public string make { set; get; }
    public string modelNumber { set; get; }
    public string information { set; get; }
    public string ownersManualLocation { set; get; }
    public string safetyChecklistSchedule { set; get; }
    public string maintenanceService { set; get; }
    public DateTime registrationExpiry { set; get; }

    public Machine(string id, string machineName, string machineType)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your constructor doesn't do anything with the parameters you give it, hence `machineName` doesn't ever get set to a value.

Comment: Wow I am very silly. I need a `this.machineName = machineName` thanks Spencer

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, you need to assign the properties from the input parameters, like this:

```
public Machine(string id, string machineName, string machineType)
{
    Id = id;
    this.machineName = machineName;
    this.machineType = machineType;
}
```

As a side note, you'll generally want to use a different name for the parameter than the property.  Microsoft's suggested naming standards use capitalized property names, so instead of `public string machineName { set; get; }`, you'd have `public string MachineName { set; get; }`

If you do that, the constructor doesn't need to prefix the properties with `this`.

Comment: Thanks John, you are correct, silly mistake after many hours of staring at screens!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use property initializers instead of a constructor.  Something like this:

```
loadedMachines.Add(new Machine() {Id = "0", machineName = "My cool Yaris", machineType = "Toyota"});
```

This kind of syntax is common when using objects that are dynamically constructed, like entities, because many frameworks don't support calling constructors with parameters on dynamic creation.